# Not able to find casandra tables in apache spark

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I started the spark by dse spark command.

Later I created a one rdd with cassandra keyspace and table ..
Trying to print contents of tables using rddname.first
But it shows couldn’t able to find keyspace or tables

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem. For guidance, see https://stackexchange.com/tour and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Comment: Hello, Anil. Do you have any updates for us? We'd love to help you out. Cheers!